# How can I display thumbnails of images in a grid and then open one image in new window using tkinter and python?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7, new-window, image-enlarge

**Update: Figured out a solution and updated as a self answer.**

I have 20 jpg images in a directory. Using Python 3.7 + Tkinter 8.6.10. I access them, resize and display them in a main Window in a a grid. The grid has 12 rows x 5 columns = 60 Frames.
All Frames in row-1 have Labels populated with resized images.
All Frames in row-2 have Labels with the text "Enlarge".
All Frames in row-3 have Labels with the text "Select".
This pattern repeats.

[image: Main Window with grid is fine, new window has no enlarged image]

On clicking "Enlarge" button, I want to display the full non-resized image in a NEW window. I am facing an issue during the display of enlarged image. A new window opens, but there is not image. I get the following error in the console:
-------------------- Console output starts --------------------

(ce7comb1) rohit@rohitu2004lts:~/PyWDUbuntu/thesis$ python3 test_gui_3.py
num of images = 20
array=
['/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/371903.jpg', '/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/2192573.jpg', '/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/1989609.jpg', '/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/1283466.jpg', '/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/371897.jpg', '/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/1624481.jpg', '/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/36979.jpg', '/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/148284.jpg', '/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/2209751.jpg', '/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/1440465.jpg', '/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/1369162.jpg', '/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/2069887.jpg', '/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/1243756.jpg', '/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/2148982.jpg', '/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/984950.jpg', '/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/1317156.jpg', '/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/1920465.jpg', '/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/1254659.jpg', '/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/2209317.jpg', '/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/371902.jpg']

n_rows = 12     n_cols = 5

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/rohit/anaconda3/envs/ce7comb1/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1705, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
File "test_gui_3.py", line 120, in do_enlarge_btn_press_functionality
image=img_orig)
File "/home/rohit/anaconda3/envs/ce7comb1/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 2766, in **init**
Widget.**init**(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
File "/home/rohit/anaconda3/envs/ce7comb1/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 2299, in **init**
(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage21" doesn't exist

-------------------- Console output ends --------------------

This is the full code for the python script, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
# importing required packages
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

img_folder = r'/home/rohit/PyWDUbuntu/thesis/Imgs2Detect_20imgs/'

image_files_list = [os.path.join(img_folder, f) \
                    for f in os.listdir(img_folder) \
                    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(img_folder, f))]
print(f"num of images = {len(image_files_list)}\narray=\n{image_files_list}")

class c_my_wnd_main_window:
    def __init__(self, _wnd_name):
        self.wnd = tk.Tk()
        self.wnd_name = _wnd_name
        self.frame_arr = None
    

def build_frames(self, _n_rows, _n_cols, _in_img_arr):
    ## create array holding skeleton form of the objects of required frame types
    self.frame_arr = []
    for r_idx in range(_n_rows):
        self.wnd.columnconfigure(r_idx, weight=1, minsize=50)
        self.wnd.columnconfigure(r_idx, weight=1, minsize=50)
        temp_array = []
        for c_idx in range(_n_cols):
            frame_name_str = ''.join( ['frm_', str(r_idx+1), '_', str(c_idx+1)] )
            if (r_idx % 3) == 0: ## picture frame
                temp_array.append(my_frm_image(self.wnd, frame_name_str))
            elif (r_idx % 3) == 1: ## enlarge frame
                temp_array.append(my_frm_enlarge(self.wnd, frame_name_str))
            else: ## select frame
                temp_array.append(my_frm_select(self.wnd, frame_name_str))
        self.frame_arr.append(temp_array)
    
    ## set the frame arrays objects as required
    img_idx = 0
    for r_idx in range(_n_rows):
        for c_idx in range(_n_cols):
            if (r_idx) % 3 == 0: ## picture frame
                self.frame_arr[r_idx][c_idx].frm_img.grid(row=r_idx,
                                                          column=c_idx,
                                                          padx=5, pady=5
                                                         )
                ## populate the image
                resized_image, file_with_path = opened_imgs_arr[img_idx]
                self.frame_arr[r_idx][c_idx].add_image(resized_image)
                img_idx += 1
                self.frame_arr[r_idx][c_idx].image_with_path = file_with_path
            elif (r_idx % 3) == 1: ## enlarge frame
                self.frame_arr[r_idx][c_idx].frm_enlarge.grid(row=r_idx,
                                                          column=c_idx,
                                                          padx=5, pady=5
                                                         )
                self.frame_arr[r_idx][c_idx].btn_enlarge.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
                self.frame_arr[r_idx][c_idx].enlarge_this_image = self.frame_arr[r_idx - 1][c_idx].image_with_path ## bcoz immediately previous row should reference the image frame
            else: ## select frame
                self.frame_arr[r_idx][c_idx].frm_select.grid(row=r_idx,
                                                          column=c_idx,
                                                          padx=5, pady=5
                                                         )
                self.frame_arr[r_idx][c_idx].btn_select.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

class my_frm_image:
    def __init__(self, _wnd, _frame_name):
        self.frm_img = tk.Frame(
            master=_wnd,
            relief=tk.SUNKEN,
            borderwidth=2)
        self.frame_name = _frame_name
        self.image_with_path = None
        self.lbl_img = tk.Label(master=self.frm_img, image=None)
        
def add_image(self, _in_img):
    #print(f" function add_image called ")
    self.lbl_img.configure(image=_in_img)
    self.lbl_img.pack(padx=1, pady=1)

class my_frm_enlarge:
    def __init__(self, _wnd, _frame_name):
        self.frm_enlarge = tk.Frame(
            master=_wnd,
            relief=tk.RAISED,
            borderwidth=4)
        self.frame_name = _frame_name
        self.enlarge_this_image = None
        self.btn_enlarge = tk.Button(
            master=self.frm_enlarge,
            text=f"Enlarge",
            bg="black", fg="white", 
            command=self.do_enlarge_btn_press_functionality
        )
        self.btn_enlarge.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
    

def do_enlarge_btn_press_functionality(self):
    #print(f"Would have enlarged image: {self.enlarge_this_image}")
    img_orig = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.enlarge_this_image))
    wnd_enlarged_img = tk.Tk()
    frm_enlarged_img = tk.Frame(
        master=wnd_enlarged_img,
        relief=tk.SUNKEN,
        borderwidth=2
    )
    #lbl_enlarged_img_path = tk.Label(master=wnd_enlarged_img, text=self.enlarge_this_image)
    #lbl_enlarged_img_path.pack()
    lbl_enlarged_img = tk.Label(
        master=wnd_enlarged_img,
        image=img_orig)
    lbl_enlarged_img.pack(padx=1, pady=1)
    frm_enlarged_img.pack()
    wnd_enlarged_img.mainloop()

class my_frm_select:
    def __init__(self, _wnd, _frame_name):
        self.frm_select = tk.Frame(
            master=_wnd,
            relief=tk.RAISED,
            borderwidth=4)
        self.frame_name = _frame_name
        self.btn_select = tk.Button(
            master=self.frm_select,
            text=f"Select",
            bg="black", fg="white",
            command=self.do_select_btn_press_functionality
        )
        self.btn_select.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
    

def do_select_btn_press_functionality(self):
    #print(f"Pressed Select button: {self.frame_name}")
    if self.btn_select["text"] == 'Select':
        ## Sink button and change text to Deselect
        self.btn_select.configure(text=f"Deselect", relief=tk.SUNKEN, bg="yellow", fg="black")
    else:
        ## Raise button and change text to Select
       self.btn_select.configure(text=f"Select", relief=tk.RAISED, bg="black", fg="white")
    return


o_main_window = c_my_wnd_main_window('main_window')

opened_imgs_arr = []
for img_idx in range(20):
    img_orig = Image.open(image_files_list[img_idx])
    img_resized = img_orig.resize((100, 80),Image.ANTIALIAS)
    ## append tuple of resized image and file with path
    opened_imgs_arr.append( (ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_resized), image_files_list[img_idx]) )
    del img_orig, img_resized

num_rows_of_images = 4
n_rows = num_rows_of_images * 3
n_cols = int(len(image_files_list) / num_rows_of_images)
print(f"n_rows = {n_rows}\t\tn_cols = {n_cols}")
o_main_window.build_frames(n_rows, n_cols, image_files_list)
o_main_window.wnd.mainloop()

print(f"\n\nNormal exit.\n\n")
```

Please help.

Comment: It is because you used multiple instances of `Tk()`.  Use `Toplevel()` instead inside `do_enlarge_btn_press_functionality()`.

Comment: Thank you. Btw, I just cracked it. I had several gaps in my understanding. Posting the working and cleaner code as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There were several things I had not figured out conceptually and some other errors too: how and why to use Toplevel windows vs the root window; how to pass parameters to the function invoked by a Button; stupid mistake specifying the window titles in some places.

If it helps anyone, uploaded full cleaned up code to github here: https://github.com/rbewoor/thesis/blob/master/GUI_related/test_gui_4.py